# How to make double quoted variable in bash to output empty instead of two single quote?

Tags: bash

I got a bash script , for example

```
[root@test ~]# cat 1.sh
#!/bin/bash
var1=""
var2=""
touch "$var1"
touch $var2
```

it output as:

```
[root@test ~]# bash -x 1.sh
+ var1=
+ var2=
+ touch ''
touch: cannot touch ‘’: No such file or directory
+ touch
touch: missing file operand
```

so if I use `"$var"` over command , when it is empty , it will become `''` and breaks my command

while if I use `$var` without double quotes , it works but shell check keep complaint to double quote to prevent word split

how can I workaround this ?

-------------edit -------

the `touch` here is example ,  please don't mind the command here , the goal is to make it output nothing

e.g.

`my_command $var1 $var2 $var3 $var4`

these var can be empty , so if I double quoted it

`my_command "$var1" "$var2" "$var3" "$var4"`

let's say if var1 and 2 is empty , then it will run as

```
var1=""
var2=""
var3="some"
var4="thing"
my_command "$var1" "$var2" "$var3" "$var4"
```

it output as

`my_command '' '' some thing` , and broken due to `''` in argument.

if I do

```
var1=""
var2=""
var3="some"
var4="thing"
my_command $var1 $var2 $var3 $var4
```

it goes as `my_command some thing`  which just works , but shell check keep complaints :(

Comment: I'm unclear what you  define as "works" here either way…!?

Comment: This is the difference between "empty argument" and "non-existent argument". The flag `-x` prints the line _as parsed by the tokenizer_. I don't see any way around that, unless you specify where your command breaks.

Comment: `touch` needs at least one valid filename as an argument; they're both broken, but the one with a quoted variable is slightly less so.

Comment: yes, sorry , it was just an example , the actual command can be anything else , like `my_comm $var1 $var2 $var3`  , in where any of them can be empty , but if I do it like `my_comm "$var1" ...` then bash -x shows it ran as `my_comm ''` and breaks

Comment: `it will become '' and breaks my command` is invalid. No, it does not "become ''". It's empty, as expected. The empty input is beeing __represented__ by the debugging output of shell as `''`. `and broken due to '' in argument.` NO.

Comment: @KamilCuk yeah .... well , so only way out is not to double quote it and ignore the shell check complains I guess ?

Comment: `so only way out` Out of what? What do you __want__?

Comment: to make `var1=""; var2="something" ; my_comm "$var1" "$var2"` to run as `my_comm something` instead of become `my_comm '' something`

Comment: Then, you do not want "empty argument", you want "without an argument". I believe that word - "empty" - is the main source of confusion. An argument may be empty, but still be there. You want to omit an argument, when it's empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can omit empty variables from an argument list like this:

```
my_command ${var1:+"$var1"} ${var2:+"$var2"} ${var3:+"$var3"} ${var4:+"$var4"}
```

Explanation: `${var:+something}` expands to `something` *if* `var` is defined and non-empty. So `${var:+"$var"}` expands to a properly double-quoted reference to `$var` *if* the variable isn't empty. If it's empty or undefined, the whole thing expands to nothing, and since the outer reference isn't double-quoted it gets eliminated by word splitting.

Answer (score 2):

When not quoted, empty string `var=""; touch $var` expands to nothing (as if you did not add it).

But when quoted `var=""; touch "$var"` then it expands to the empty string from `var` and this is an invalid filename argument to `touch`.

Comment: sorry about the confusion , the touch here is just an example , it can be any other command

Answer (score 1):

> how can I workaround this ?

There is nothing to workaround as it works as expected. The presented command `touch "$var"` works as expected. When `var` is empty, one empty argument is being passed to `touch` command.

As creating a file with empty name is invalid, happily `touch` complains with a message.

> the goal is to make it output nothing

Then check if the argument to `touch` is non-empty before running it.

```
if [ -n "$var" ]; then
    somecommand "$var"
fi
```

If you want to omit an argument from a list if it's empty, use bash array to accumulate existing arguments and pass them properly quoted to the command:

```
args=()
if [[ -n "$var1" ]]; then
   args+=("$var1")
fi
if [[ -n "$var2" ]]; then
   args+=("$var2")
fi
somecommand "${args[@]}"
```

The POSIX compatible alternatives to bash arrays is to use `set -- "$@" "$var"` posititional arguments to accumulate the arguments or `str+="$(printf " %q" "$var")` properly quoted string to be `eval`ulated.

If you want to "make it output nothing" literally, then silence `stdout` and `stderr` of a command, typically by redirecting to `/dev/null`:

```
{ somecommand ...; } >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the validity of your variables before trying to use them. For example, you can use [`if [[ -z $VAR ]]`](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html):

```
if [[ -z $var1 || -z $var2 || -z $var3 || -z $var4 ]]; then
  echo "Error: argument cannot be empty"
  exit 1
fi

my_command "$var1" "$var2" "$var3" "$var4"
```

You can also split it into various `if`s in case you want different messages for each one, for example.

Comment: :) thanks for the advice , but the var can be empty ,  `if -z` is my last resort if I can't find any other way though :(